# Django, postgres: IntegrityError null value in column, but column should accept null

Tags: django, python-unittest

I have this model:

```
Class Job(models.Model):
    // Some fields
    slug = models.SlugField(verbose_name=_("slug"), max_length=151, null=True, blank=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):                                      
        return reverse("jobs", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})
```

Slug should accept Null value. And it does. For example, I create this on the shell, and it works ok:

```
In [1]: j = Job.objects.create(title="my faked title",date_start=aware_start, date_end=aware_end, amount_to_pay=10, email='fake@gmail.com')

In [2]: j
Out[2]: <Job: my faked title>
```

But if I want to test it, on a test case, it fails.

The test case is:

```
class JobCreationTest(TestCase):
  def test_simple_creation(self):                                              
    import datetime                                                          
    import pytz                                                              
    aware_start = datetime.datetime(2011, 8, 15, 8, 15, 12, 0, pytz.UTC)     
    aware_end = datetime.datetime(2012, 8, 15, 8, 15, 12, 0, pytz.UTC)       
    Job.objects.create(title="my faked title",date_start=aware_start, date_end=aware_end, amount_to_pay=10, email='fake@gmail.com')
```

And the error trace is:

```
self = <django.db.backends.utils.CursorWrapper object at 0x7fc2bc72af28>
sql = 'INSERT INTO "posts_job" ("id", "created_at", "created_by_id", "updated_at", "updated_by_id", "deleted", "title", "ema...slug") VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)'
params = (UUID('e814e054-e273-4316-b670-f39584f0b3ef'), datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 19, 9, 39, 31, 31514, tzinfo=<UTC>), None, datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 19, 9, 39, 31, 31566, tzinfo=<UTC>), None, False, ...)
ignored_wrapper_args = (False, {'connection': <django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis.base.DatabaseWrapper object at 0x7fc2d0486f28>, 'cursor': <django.db.backends.utils.CursorWrapper object at 0x7fc2bc72af28>})

    def _execute(self, sql, params, *ignored_wrapper_args):
        self.db.validate_no_broken_transaction()
        with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
            if params is None:
                return self.cursor.execute(sql)
            else:
>               return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
E               django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "slug" violates not-null constraint
E               DETAIL:  Failing row contains (e814e054-e273-4316-b670-f39584f0b3ef, 2019-03-19 09:39:31.031514+00, null, 2019-03-19 09:39:31.031566+00, null, f, my faked title, fake@gmail.com, , null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 2011-08-15 08:15:12+00, 2012-08-15 08:15:12+00, null, null, null, , , 10, null).
```

UPDATE:

```
$ ./manage.py makemigrations posts
No changes detected in app 'posts'
$ ./manage.py migrate posts
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: posts
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
```

And in the table definition, into psql

```
> \d+ posts_job
                        Table "public.posts_job"
        Column        |           Type           | Collation | Nullable | 
----------------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+-
 id                   | uuid                     |           | not null | 
 title                | character varying(128)   |           | not null | 
 email                | character varying(254)   |           | not null | 
 slug                 | character varying(151)   |           |          |
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you changed your code and those changes are not made in the database.
You may try to run:

`./manage.py makemigrations && ./manage.py migrate`

and try again.
Reference to [Django migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/migrations/) documentation.

Comment: Sorry, I did not clarify that.. no migrations pending... also in psql table inspection, it says nothing in the column of 'Not Null' .. I will update with this info

Comment: @Gonzalo is that an inspection of test database? you can run the test with --keepdb so you can inspect the test db meanwhile

Comment: @Gonzalo you should inspect the correct database, database used in test will have a different name https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/testing/overview/#the-test-database

Comment: True! In the testing database, the slug field figures as "non null" .. so that's the problem, is like the migrations were not applied in the test database.

Comment: @Gonzalo reuse-db with no migration is not a good idea when you change your schema. At least now you know why exactly :)

Answer (score 0):

I have realised that I have this on my pytest config.

```
[pytest]
addopts = --nomigrations --reuse-db
```

So, migrations were not applied on test database. (Before slug field was required, and now is not)

So I solved it, executing with --create-db parameter

```
pytest posts/tests/test_api_post.py --create-db
```

REF: [pytest --create-db parameter](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/database.html#example-work-flow-with-reuse-db-and-create-db)